# What happened to Fraulein Rottenmeier from Heidi (1937)?

Tags: plot-explanation, heidi

Towards the end of the movie "Heidi", after the Police Lieutenant says that they should wait and hear what Herr Sesemann has to say about the Grandfather, Heidi runs to him and Fraulein Rottenmeier is last seen standing looking worried. What happened to her? Did she go to Jail? They never say what happened to her. My Mother loves this Movie and she has always wondered what happened to her.